# DotNetNuke SiteLog Differs from aspnet_Membership

Tags: asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke, membership-provider

We are using DNN 6.2.6 and I have the SiteLog feature turned on.  When I query the DNN **SiteLog** table to see when a user has logged in, ***the latest is: 9/4/2013***

```
SELECT u.[UserID] DNNID
  ,u.[Username] 
  ,u.[FirstName] [First Name]
  ,u.[LastName] [Last Name]
  ,u.[DisplayName] [Display Name]
  ,sl.[DateTime] [Access Date] 
  , r.RoleName [Role]
  , t.TabName [Page Name]
FROM [dnnDB].[dbo].[SiteLog] sl 
LEFT JOIN dnnDB.dbo.Users u on u.UserID = sl.UserId 
LEFT JOIN dnnDB.dbo.UserRoles ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID 
LEFT JOIN dnnDB.dbo.Roles r on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID 
LEFT JOIN dnnDB.dbo.Tabs t on sl.TabId = t.TabID 
WHERE 1=1 
AND u.Username = 'JDoe' 
AND sl.[DateTime] >= DATEADD(YYYY, -1, getdate())
ORDER by [Access Date] desc
```

But, when I look at the **aspnet_Membership** table's `LastLoginDate` , ***it shows 9/23/2013***:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dnnDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]
WHERE userid = 'ABCDEF12-1234-ABCD-ABCD-AD5BAA5C7EBF'
```

Any ideas why they are not in sync?

Is the `aspnet_Membership` accurate? or `SiteLog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that _Membership is more accurate, Sitelog probably recognizes the actual login itself, where _Membership recognizes that the user last visited the site on the 23rd?

That's just my assumption though, I haven't had a chance to go through the code to confirm.